# Counting words in python from the text file

Tags: python

Need to open text file and find numbers of occurrences for the names given in the other file. Program should write name; count pairs, separated by semicolons into the file with .csv format

It should look like:

Jane; 77

Hector; 34

Anna; 39

...

Tried to use "Counter" but then it looks like a list, so I think that this is a wrong way to do the task

```
import re
import collections
from collections import Counter

wanted = re.findall('\w+', open('iliadcounts.csv').read().lower())
cnt = Counter()
words = re.findall('\w+', open('pg6130.txt').read().lower())
for word in words:
    if word in wanted:
        cnt[word] += 1
print (cnt)
```

but this is definitely not the right code for this task...

Answer (score 1):

You can feed the whole list of words to Counter at once, it will count it for you.
You can then print only the words in `wanted` by iterating over it:

```
import re
import collections
from collections import Counter

# create some demo data as I do not have your data at hand - uses your filenames
def create_demo_files():     
    with open('iliadcounts.csv',"w") as f:
        f.write("hug,crane,box")
    with open('pg6130.txt',"w") as f:
        f.write("hug,shoe,blues,crane,crane,box,box,box,wood")

create_demo_files()


# work with your files
with open('iliadcounts.csv') as f:
    wanted = re.findall('\w+', f.read().lower())
with open('pg6130.txt') as f:
    cnt = Counter( re.findall('\w+', f.read().lower()) )


# printed output for all words in wanted (all words are counted)
for word in wanted:
    print("{}; {}".format(word, cnt.get(word)))

    # would work as well: 
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting
    # print(f"{word}; {cnt.get(word)}")
```

Output:

```
hug; 1
crane; 2
box; 3
```

Or you can print the whole Counter:

```
 print(cnt)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'box': 3, 'crane': 2, 'hug': 1, 'shoe': 1, 'blues': 1, 'wood': 1})
```

Links:

- https://pyformat.info/
- [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting)
- [with open(...) as f:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: If the words are in .txt file, then what should I write in f.write? Sorry, I really don't understand python

Comment: @jan I just created some demodata - you already have the data in your files you want to count, don't you? You do not need to call `create_demo_data()` - simply operate on your files.

Comment: So if my words are names(Paris,Helen,Hector) I don't need to write them there?

Comment: You get the words you want from the file `'iliadcounts.csv'` - you count these words inside `'pg6130.txt'` - I do not think the code you posted as "yours" is really yours if I look at what you asked in the comments to my answer ....

Comment: Yes, I googled and found some examples but personally I'm totally 0 in python... understand something but not this task